# Cannot find module '@mdx-js/mdx' - Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gatsby

**After the last update of today i'm getting this error. I'm using no MDX in my project howsoever..**

**npm run develop** produces this issue, does someone has some knowledge about this?

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@mdx-js/mdx'
Require stack:
- /Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/transform-recipe-mdx.js
- /Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/renderer/index.js
- /Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/validate-steps.js
- /Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/recipe-machine/index.js
- /Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/graphql-server/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/transform-recipe-mdx.js:12:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/transform-recipe-mdx.js',
    '/Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/renderer/index.js',
    '/Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/validate-steps.js',
    '/Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/recipe-machine/index.js',
    '/Users/mikey/Sites/Gimmix/node_modules/gatsby-recipes/dist/graphql-server/server.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: What update are you meaning?

Comment: @FerranBuireu "gatsby": "^2.24.54", "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.8.33", "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.28" etc...

Comment: I get this exact error when I upgrade `gatsby` from 2.24.37 to 2.24.54. I have never used MDX either but the error points at `mdx-js` being a dependency of `gatsby-recipes` which must be a dependency of `gatsby` itself I'd guess.

Comment: @a_rts I think it's an error/bug from gatsby itself, and we have to wait for a fix in the coming updates. (?) so don't push your files live, keep them local.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Problem is solved with the latest update(s):

gatsby@2.24.5
(gatsby-plugin-sharp@2.6.33)
(gatsby-source-contentful@2.3.43)
(gatsby-transformer-remark@2.8.34)

**delete your cache**
`gatsby clean`

Be sure to also update your gatsby-cli: `npm i -g gatsby-cli`

**delete your node_modules & packages for a clean install**
`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`

**last but not least**
`npm install --save`

**and test your building proces**
`npm run develop`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend downgrading to your latest stable version of your Gatsby dependency (to `v2.24.37`). It seems to be a common issue in `^2.24.54` versions. As you may guess, although you are not using the `@mdx-js/mdx` package, it's a dependency used by Gatsby itself.

In the upgrade process for any package, when a dependency is upgraded doesn't mean that all their sub-depenencies work because of the needs of each project. It may take a few days/weeks to work for all packages. That's why you should ensure in a `gatsby dev` and `gatsby build` that the project works before committing and pushing anything to the repository.

If you haven't committed the upgrade, just rollback the tracked files (`git checkout .` or `git reset --hard`), remove your `node_modules` and run a `npm install` command to keep the project in your stable running version.

If you have committed your files, run `npm install gatsby@2.24.37` to downgrade your Gatsby version (or fix it in your `package.json`) and run a `npm install` again.

---

I saw in your comments that you have the dependency in your `package.json` but you are not using it. In that case remove it by `npm uninstall  @mdx-js/mdx`.

Comment: Yes. I haven't pushed it yet. Thanks for the tip. I will wait for the next update to come and keep the files locally. 

And I said I don't have the package in my list, so thats why i find it strange.. But even that isn't the problem, cause the "mdx/js" was in my node_modules before the whole update. So the update is just messy at this moment..

Comment: In that case just rollback your local changes, delete your `node_modules` and run `npm install`. Because it's a dev dependency of Gatsby it will be in your modules but with the correct version.

Comment: I have, but still bumb into the same warning. Its a gatsby bug, i think..

Answer (score 1):

Running `yarn add @mdx-js/mdx` fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, i didn't tried it because Gatsby already fixed it with the latest update(s).

Answer (score 0):

You first make sure that all dependencies are installed properly.

You can check that is this module installed or not by importing `import {<name>} from '@mdx-js'`

If it doesn't break it means that it is installed already.
Or if it breaks then run `npm install` to install all the listed dependencies.

You can move forward and check that this package has that file or data that you want.

You can check this with `import {<name>} from '@mdx-js/mdx'`. You can also check this with navigating to `node_modules/@mdx-js/mdx` directory. You will find some names of data you can use, functions or objects etc. Name must match from one of the data type else you have a typo when you are importing something.

Note: this is a general debugging approach for node_modules

Comment: Thanks, i'm a newbie. Saw your first deleted post my friend. Don't worry, can have it. 

Not sure if i understand you but I'm not using any MDX or markdown files in my project, everything comes from a headless CMS. Why calling it then? I saw howsoever that after deleting and reinstalling (for updating) my packages (what i always do), it added the '@mdx-js/mdx' to the package.lock.json. Now its expecting me to use it.

Comment: correction: *I saw howsoever that after deleting and reinstalling (for updating) my packages (what i always do), it updated the '@mdx-js/mdx' in the package.lock.json.

Comment: If saying you a newbie hearted, I apologise. 

Can you please share your package.json file here?

Comment: I cannot paste it in here, its has too many characters. I'm really a newbie on Stackoverflow, eventhough im here for years. Do you know another way to share it.. (?)

Comment: Aaah good one, thanks I will in the future, for now its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

run `yarn run build` and fix those errors. That fixed my problem!